# Data in regions of HBase could manually be arranged on basis of family:column's value

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I've been working on HBase from a couple of week, still in design state for my project with an ongoing POC. Now before i ask my query let me give brief description of what i've inferenced.

The basic unit of horizontal scalability in HBase is called a Region. Regions are a subset of the table’s data and they are essentially a contiguous, sorted range of rows that are stored together.
when regions become too large after adding more rows, the region is split into two at the middle key, creating two roughly equal halves.

The multi-map structure of a HBase table can thus be summarized as
key -> family -> column -> timestamp -> value.

HBase, internally, keeps special catalog tables named -ROOT- and .META. within which it maintains the current list, state, and location of all regions afloat on the cluster. The -ROOT- table holds the list of .META. table regions. The .META. table holds the list of all user-space regions. Entries in these tables are keyed by region name, where a region name is made of the table name the region belongs to, the region’s start row, its time of creation, and finally, an MD5 hash of all of the former

Numbers of rows that can be stored in a region depends upon threshold value defined for a region i.e. this is something what i believe can be given manually.

SO what i want to do is :-

If a table with USERID , ROLE & YEAR is their with lets say millions of tuples. I want to create two layers.
One layer with region nodes differentiated on year's range. lets say one region stored data from 1990 - 1995 , another stores data from 1996 - 2000 and so on.
& second layer having differentiated on roles. for example one region node keeps data for admin (id -1), another for users(id -2) and so on.
Each layer has its own region server and mapped in meta table and meta table managed by ZOOKEEPER.
Refer below figure for further clarification :-
[image]

Perhaps more than one zookeepers may work in sync managed by another zookeeper above them.

So this is the design what i'll be proposing and i want to inquire about its feasibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the two tables, hbase will automatically do the splitting and rebalancing if needed.
If you want to manually pre-split the table, on creation you can specify the set of key-ranges that you want, for each table, and hbase will create one region per range. then the balancer will take care of distributing the different regions to different machines.
You don't need to care about Zookeeper, -ROOT- or .META.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/how-scaling-really-works-in-apache-hbase/

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. what i could understand as per your response, i can manually define range for a region(s) but all those regions will be kept in sync by whom. Isn't this zookeeper's job ??

Comment: ZooKeeper is only used to store some metadata to "bootstrap" the client and internally to keep track of transient states (see this post for more details http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/what-are-hbase-znodes). but for the client point of view ZooKeeper is only used to get the address of the META table (the RS hosting the META). Once you have the META table you have the mappings between Region Servers and regions. When you do a "Put" or a "Get" META is consulted to ask the question "which machine is responsible to handle this key", and the request is sent to the region server.

Comment: let say that you create a table with a single region and start inserting data. HBase will add that region to the META table and the Assignment/Balancer will select a Region Server to host that region. Once the region grows too much. The region is split in two (so meta now contains 2 regions for that table) and so on... From the client point of view you don't have to care about regions just insert your data. (unless you want to manually partition your table see the SPLIT argument of create table)